# Spark 2 logisticregression remove threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, distributed-computing

I'm using Spark 2 + Scala to train LogisticRegression based binary classification model and I'm using `import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression`, which is the new ml API in Spark 2. However, when I evaluated the model by AUROC, I did not find a way to use the probability (double in 0-1) instead of binary classification (0/1). This was previously achieved by `removeThreshold()`, but in `ml.LogisticRegression` I did not find a similar method. Thus, is there a way to do that?

The evaluator I'm using is

```
val evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setRawPredictionCol("rawPrediction")
  .setMetricName("areaUnderROC")
val auroc = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)`
```

Comment: Actually it looks like if setRawPredictionCol to probability, it should use probability instead of prediction. Could someone confirm that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to get probability output other than 0/1 output, try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary, LogisticRegression}
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(100)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
val lrModel = lr.fit(trainData)
val summary = lrModel.summary
summary.predictions.select("probability").show()
```

Comment: In this way, where is the test data?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary,
LogisticRegression}
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(100).setRegParam(0.3)
val lrModel = lr.fit(trainData)  
val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
val predictions = lrModel.transform(test)
predictions.select("label", "probability").show()
```